# In Javascript, is there a way to make strict comparison "greater than" or "smaller than" operations?

Tags: javascript, comparison, operation, weak

Is there a way in Javascript to make strict comparison operations other than the one allowed with '===', i.e., a strict '<', '>', '<=' and '>='?

The code below using '<' performs a weak operation between a string and an integer. I would like to know if this could be achieved as done with '==='.

```
let a = '9';
let b = 10;
if (a < b) {
    console.log('Success');
}  // Prints 'Success'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Familiarize yourself with how [IsLessThan](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islessthan) works. How do you expect a “strict” `<` to work, precisely?

Comment: I would expect it to return some kind of falsy value, since one of the values is not a number. I will look into that method, thank you!

Comment: This isn't possible in JavaScript, but with TypeScript, you'll get a compiler error: https://tsplay.dev/mAr1XW - Consider switching to TypeScript :)

Comment: Excellent, good to know that. I'm yet to learn TS, will sooner or later do. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such set of operators. Also they would violate the usual expectation that `(a < b) != (a >= b)` / `(a <= b) != (a > b)`<sup>1</sup>.

Of course you can build this yourself by writing

```
if (typeof a == typeof b && a < b) …
```

<sub>1: this expectation doesn't actually hold for the normal operators either, there are values like `NaN` that violate it.</sub>

Comment: Not a very elegant solution but does the work. Thanks!